# Update table with value from the same table using a sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I using sqlite and have a table that looks like:

[image: my table]

I am trying to update refer column with values from col2 corresponding col1

I tried query like

```
update tab1 
set refer = (select col2 from tab1 where col1 = refer) 
where col1 = 2
```

This but is not working.

I have also tried

```
update tab1 
set refer = (select tem1.col2 
             from tab1 tem1, tab1 tem2 
             where tem1.col1 = tem2.refer and tem2.col1=2) 
where col1 = 2
```

This works.

But I am not sure whether this is the correct way to do.

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Tuf.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UPDATE rows with values from the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504406/update-rows-with-values-from-the-same-table)

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using? (Remove the tags for the products not involved.)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: please post the expected result

Comment: which db are using ??

Comment: I am using sqlite also updated the expected image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your code  seesm tha you need

```
   update tab1 
   set refer = col2  
   when col1 = refer 
   and col1 = 2
```

that mean

```
   update tab1 
   set refer = col2  
   when  refer  2
```

oherwise fi yoru are looking for an update on the same table with subquery you should could use an inner join

in mysql

```
 update tab1 
 INNER JOIN (
      select col1, col2 
      from tab1 
      where col1 = refer ) t t.col1 = tabl1.col1 and  col1 = 2
```

in  sqllite you could use

```
  update tab1 
  set refer = (select t.col2 from (
  select col2 from tab1 where col1 = refer
  ) t )
  where col1 = 2
```

Comment: sorry got one brace missing.It works, how different is it from the one I have used and which is better?

Comment: It works, how different is it from the one I have used and which is better?

Comment: the different is based  on the fact that the two inner subselect force the db engine to create a temp table and so the update don't work on the same  .. table  ..which is better ? ,,mine is more clear  .. you are using  unuseful cartesian product for obtain the same  .. but for large table your produce performance problems

Comment: the same query is not working with `where col1=5` it is updating as Null, can you help @scaisEdge

Comment: I think it is not working sometimes it is updating with null value. @scaisEdge

Comment: for col1 =5 the refer is 2 so it should be replaced by b
`update tab1 
  set refer = (select t.col2 from (
  select col2 from tab1 where col1 = refer
  ) t )
  where col1 = 5`

Comment: where as this query woks fine all the times
`update tab1 
set refer = (select tem1.col2 
             from tab1 tem1, tab1 tem2 
             where tem1.col1 = tem2.refer and tem2.col1=5) 
where col1 = 5`

Answer (score 0):

Finally this query works perfectly:

```
update tab1 
set refer = (select t1.col2 from tab1 as t1 where t1.col1 = tab1.refer) 
where tab1.col1 = 2
```